# How to show image from api call in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs-observables

HI I have a api call and want to show the image from the property: welcomePopupImage: string;

Comment: What is the value `result.welcomePopupImage` holding?

Comment: I am not sure what is happening ? But just from debugging perspective , when you hit the url http://localhost:50762/resources/image/4366232f-0b89-4fdc-91cb-f98cbe0cf998.jpg , do you see the image ?

Comment: That is string the id of image.. Yes I see the image

Comment: But I dont see it if I do this:   <img [attr.src]="'../Resource/Image/'+ result.welcomePopupImage" alt="" />

Comment: Then I get errors: Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 15 in [{'./Resource/'+ result.welcomePopupImage}]

Comment: Here I created a working DEMO for you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eczhcb?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: as mentioned in the answer below: you are trying to fetch the image from `Resource`, not `resources`. probably just URL that's broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file path is incorrect. You have ./Resource/ but above you have /resources/ . The s is missing in your img src.